# Calculate outcome from two selects into a new Select

Tags: sql, nested

I have two Selects:

```
SELECT SUM(BetragSw) FROM bi_Budget WHERE Konto_KontoNrFIB = Buchungen_KontoNrFIB  and Konto_KontoNrFIB = '344100'

SELECT SUM(BetragSw) FROM bi_Budget WHERE Konto_KontoNrFIB = GegKontoNr  and GegKontoNr = '344100'
```

Now i have to make a new select around this two where i want to calculate value from first select - second select.

I can't make it work..

Lets say results Select 1 = 100 , Select 2 = 60. My goal is to have only one column with a Total of 40 (100-60)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use you want to do afterwards, but strictly speaking about the example, this should work. Note that second select has been *(-1)

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(BetragSw) AS AMOUNT 
     FROM bi_Budget 
     WHERE Konto_KontoNrFIB = Buchungen_KontoNrFIB  
       AND Konto_KontoNrFIB = '344100'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -SUM(BetragSw) AS AMOUNT 
    FROM bi_Budget 
    WHERE Konto_KontoNrFIB = GegKontoNr 
      AND GegKontoNr = '344100') AS X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to get your desired result with a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Konto_KontoNrFIB = Buchungen_KontoNrFIB AND Konto_KontoNrFIB = '344100' THEN BetragSw ELSE 0 END) -
       SUM(CASE WHEN Konto_KontoNrFIB = GegKontoNr AND GegKontoNr = '344100' THEN BetragSw ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM bi_Budget
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Konto_KontoNrFIB = Buchungen_KontoNrFIB THEN BetragSw
                WHEN Konto_KontoNrFIB = GegKontoNr THEN - BetragSw
                ELSE 0
           END)
FROM bi_Budget
WHERE Konto_KontoNrFIB = '344100';
```